# How do I get the list of Audit tables in my database?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, drop-down-menu

I need to populate a drop down list in my ASP.NET application with the list of Audit tables existing in my Oracle database. All the Audit table names start with `AUD_`.

Is there any query that can select the list of these audit tables? If not, what is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_objects WHER object_name LIKE 'AUD%'
```